# Informatica job log files process through shell scripting

Tags: scripting, hadoop

Log file raw data :

```
READER_1_1_1> BIGQUERYV2_10000 [2022-11-04 01:55:20.724] [INFO] Job statistics - \n Job ID [job_PsfUvYJkPeBfecxeIzUUrIIa9TEc] \n Job creation time [2022-11-04 01:54:54.724] , \n Job start time [2022-11-04 01:54:54.936], \n Job end time [2022-11-04 01:55:10.88], \n Bytes processed [4,081,564,561] .

DIRECTOR> CMN_1740 [2022-11-04 03:25:53.269] Table: [src_BQ_CONSUMER_CURRENT] (Instance Name: [src_BQ_CONSUMER_CURRENT] Instance UI Name: [src_BQ_CONSUMER_CURRENT])

     Output Rows [2104173], Affected Rows [2104173], Applied Rows [2104173], Rejected Rows [0]
DIRECTOR> CMN_1740 [2022-11-04 03:25:53.269] Table: [Account] (Instance Name: [Account] Instance UI Name: [TGT_ACCOUNT])

     Output Rows [2103334], Affected Rows [0], Applied Rows [2103334], Rejected Rows [839]
DIRECTOR> CMN_1740 [2022-11-04 03:25:53.269] Table: [EU_Delta_Account_txt] (Instance Name: [EU_Delta_Account_txt] Instance UI Name: [tgt_FILE])

     Output Rows [1], Affected Rows [1], Applied Rows [1], Rejected Rows [0]
DIRECTOR> TM_6020 [2022-11-04 03:25:53.269] Session [s_mtt_0117JZ0Z000000000047] completed at [Fri Nov 04 03:25:53 2022].
```

Need to capture fields like `Table:,Job start time, completed at,appended rows,error rows` data into another file. These fields data store it in Hadoop hive table for mail send.